# Customer custom value not saving to customer_enitity table

Tags: magento2.3, customer

I have created new column in customer_entity table

```
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface{

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(),'1.0.6'<0)){

            $customerName = $setup->getTable('customer_entity');

            if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($customerName) == true) {

                $connection = $setup->getConnection();

                $connection->addColumn(
                    $customerName,
                    'family_name',
                    [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'length' => 100,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'Family Name'
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
}
```

and i am creating a customer programmatically.

```
$customerFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
$newCustomer = $customerFactory->create(); 
$newCustomer->setWebsiteId($this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getId());
$newCustomer->setEmail('email@email.com');
$newCustomer->setFirstname('First name');
$newCustomer->setLastname('Last name');
$newCustomer->setPassword('Password');
.....
$newCustomer->setData('family_name', $externalUser['FamilyName']);
$newCustomer->save();
```

But only **family_name** (custom field) is not storing in customer_entity table.

Is this the proper way to store custom field ?

```
$newCustomer->setData('family_name', $externalUser['FamilyName']);
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below code

If already created **InstallSchema.php** in your module then create **UpgradeSchema.php** for creating a new column in customer_entity table

> **File**: Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

/**
 * Class UpgradeSchema
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6') < 0) {

            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable('customer_entity'),
            'family_name',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Family Name'
            ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Then create customer attributes using **InstallData** or **UpgradeData**. If already exist **InstallData** then create **UpgradeData** for creating customer attribute

> **File**:-Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory 
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var SalesSetupFactory
     */
    private $salesSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var QuoteSetupFactory
     */
    private $quoteSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory 
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory 
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;


    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
     * @param QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory,
        QuoteSetupFactory $quoteSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
        $this->quoteSetupFactory = $quoteSetupFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {


        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6') < 0) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();


            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'family_name', [
                'type' => 'static',
                'label' => 'Family Name',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
                null,
                'family_name');

            $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'family_name')
                ->addData([
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_register_address','customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create']
                ])->save();;

        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I was Save attribute in **observer** using below code but it helps you for saving custom attribute

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CustomerRegister implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $customerRepository;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ){
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        if(!$customer instanceof \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer){
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customer->getId());
        }

        /* Save customer Custom*/
        $controller = $observer->getAccountController();
        $family_name = $controller->getRequest()->getParam('family_name');

        $customer->setData('family_name', $family_name)
        ->save();

        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getId());
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('family_name', $family_name);
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

    }
}
```

I hope this code helps you to save customer custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line of code

```
 $newCustomer->setData('family_name', $externalUser['FamilyName']);
```

with the following line of code:

```
$newCustomer->setFamilyName( $externalUser['FamilyName']);
```