# Magento 2 - Can’t save custom Customer attribute value in observer customer_save_after_data_object

Tags: customer, event-observer, custom-attributes, savedata

I have created three custom attributes for Customer: **myapp_id**, **codice_univoco** and **indirizzo_pec**

[image]

If I enter a value in **codice_univoco** and/or **indirizzo_pec**, data is successfully saved:

[image]

However, when I insert a value for **myapp_id** (App ID), and then save, all custom attributes are emptied (including **myapp_id**):

[image: Image 3]

If I check my database, I can see that custom attribute values are first added…

[image]

…and then deleted from **customer_entity_varchar** table

[image]

But I know the reason why.

It is because of the following observer I wrote to handle **customer_save_after_data_object**: (the culprit is the line **$customer->save();**):

```
   /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute (\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        //Return new customer data
        $customerDataObject = $observer->getData("customer_data_object");

        //Returns old customer data
        $origCustomerDataObject = $observer->getData("orig_customer_data_object");

        if (is_null($origCustomerDataObject)) {

            return;
        }

        //if is first update confirm and send email
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRegistry->retrieve($customerDataObject->getId());

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            return $this;
        }

         if (!$this->isConfirmed($customer) && 
             $customer->getData("myapp_id") && 
            !$customer->getData("sent_email")
        ) {

            //confirm and send email
            $customer->setConfirmation(null);
            $customer->setData("sent_email",1);
            $customer->save();
        }

        return $this;
 }
```

**Note**: custom attribute **sent_email** is not saved too.

In other words, If I save a customer inside the observer, custom  data is not saved.

If I remove the line **$customer->save();** everything works fine.

**It is driving me crazy.**

### Additional information:

#### "app_id" custom attribute definition in InstallData.php

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(

    Customer::ENTITY,
    'myapp_id',
    [
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'App ID',
        'input' => 'text',
        'source' => '',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'position' => 333,
        'system' => false,
        'backend' => ''
    ]
);

$customerAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'myapp_id');
$customerAttribute->addData([ 'used_in_forms' => [ 'adminhtml_customer' ] ]);
$customerAttribute->save();
```

#### "sent_email" custom attribute definition in InstallData.php

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'sent_email', [
    'type' => 'int',
    'label' => 'Sent Email',
    'input' => 'boolean',
    'source' => '',
    'required' => true,
    'visible' => false,
    'position' => 333,
    'system' => false,
    'backend' => '',
    'default' => 0
]);

$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'sent_email')
->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
        'adminhtml_customer'
    ]
]);

$attribute->save();
```

#### "codice_univoco" custom attribute definition in UpgradeData.php

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {

$codiceunivoco = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'codice_univoco');

if (!$codiceunivoco->getId()) {

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'codice_univoco',
        [
            'type'         => 'varchar',
            'label'        => 'Codice univoco',
            'input'        => 'text',
            'required'     => true,
            'visible'      => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'position'     => 999,
            'system'       => 0,
        ]
    );

    $codiceunivoco = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'codice_univoco');
}

$codiceunivoco->setData(
    'used_in_forms',
    ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create']

);

$codiceunivoco->save();
```

#### "indirizzo_pec" custom attribute definition in UpgradeData.php

```
$indirizzopec = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'indirizzo_pec');

if (!$indirizzopec->getId()) {

    // Add Indirizzo Pec

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'indirizzo_pec',
        [
            'type'         => 'varchar',
            'label'        => 'Indirizzo Pec',
            'input'        => 'text',
            'required'     => false,
            'visible'      => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'position'     => 999,
            'system'       => 0,
        ]
    );

    $indirizzopec = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'indirizzo_pec');

}

$indirizzopec->setData(
    'used_in_forms',
    [
        'adminhtml_customer',
        'customer_account_create'
    ]

);

$indirizzopec->save();
```

**Note 2**: don't know if it is important: I have assigned a custom attribute with the same name (**app_id**) to other two entities: **Category** and **Customer Address**

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311859/customer-custom-value-not-saving-to-customer-enitity-table/311861#311861

Comment: Many, many thanks Devidas. **It worked!**

Comment: Most Welcome @ftorre

Answer (score 1):

Many, many thanks to [Devidas](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/55702/devidas) who pointed me in the  right direction (see first comment to my question) .

Here's what I've learned so far:

Consider two use-case scenario:

1. **Custom attribute is set by User in a form**
2. **Custom attribute is set in code**

Let's examine them in details

### Scenario 1: Custom attribute set by User

Four conditions must be met in order for custom attribute values to be saved to database:

1. Set the attribute option **"system" => 0** in attribute parameters inside the **install/upgrade script**

```
       $customerSetup->addAttribute(
       Customer::ENTITY,
       'sent_email',
       [
            …

            'system' => 0,

            …
         ]
       );
```

2. Assign your attribute to the entity **attribute set** inside the **install/upgrade** script

```
   $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
      CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
      CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
      null,
      'sent_email');

      $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
         Customer::ENTITY, 'sent_email')
            ->addData([
            …

            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,

            …
      ])->save();
```

3. Assign your attribute to the entity **attribute group** inside the **install/upgrade** script

```
   $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
      Customer::ENTITY, 'sent_email')
      ->addData([
      …

      'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,

      …
   ])->save();
```

In this case entity is **Customer**, but it could be **Product**, **Category**, etc.

4. Avoid using **getData()** and/or **setData()** to access/change custom attribute values.

   Use **magic methods** instead.

   I.e. to get custom attribute **sent_email** do **not** use:

```
      $customer->getData('sent_email');
```

.     use:

```
      $customer->getSentEmail();
```

### Scenario 2: Custom attribute set in code

In addition to meeting all conditions of the first use-case scenario, you must back your custom attribute with a custom field in the core entity table, like this:

```
   $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
      $setup->getTable('customer_entity'),
      'sent_email',
      [
         'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
         'nullable' => true, 
         'comment' => 'Sent email'
      ]
     );
```

Be sure to flush cache storage before data get persistently saved.

Although your attributes are created, the cache is what triggers the data to be saved afterwards.

Here is the full code of a sample module where the concepts discussed above are applied.

**job_title** is a custom **Customer** attribute whose value can be set by User in a form.

**sent_email** is a custom **Customer** attribute whose value is set programmatically in code inside an observer.

**magentostackexchange\Sample\etc\events.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd>

   <event name="customer_save_after_data_object">

      <observer instance=
         "Magentostackexchange\Sample\Observer\Customer\SaveAfterDataObject" name="magentostackexchange_sample_observer_customer_saveafterdataobject_customer_save_after_data_object"/>

      </event>
   </config>
```

**magentostackexchange\Sample\etc\module.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"           ù
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
         "urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xs">

      <module name="Magentostackexchange_Sample" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
         <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
         </sequence>
      </module>
   </config>
```

**magentostackexchange\Sample\Observer\Customer\SaveAfterDataObject.php**

```
   <?php

   namespace Magentostackexchange\Sample\Observer\Customer;

   use \Exception;
   use Magento\Customer\Model\Authentication;
   use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry;
   use Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification;

   class SaveAfterDataObject implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
   {

      /**
      * @var CustomerRegistry  $customerRegistry
      */
      protected $customerRegistry;

      /**
      * @var EmailNotification $emailNotification
      */
      protected $emailNotification;

      /**
      * @var Authentication $customerAuthentication
      */
      protected $customerAuthentication;

      /**
      * Constructor 
      * 
      * @param CustomerRegistry  $customerRegistry      
      * @param EmailNotification $emailNotification     
      * @param Authentication    $customerAuthentication
      */
      public function __construct(
         CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
         EmailNotification $emailNotification,
         Authentication $customerAuthentication
      )
      {
         $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
         $this->emailNotification = $emailNotification;
         $this->customerAuthentication = $customerAuthentication;
      }

      /**
      * Execute observer
      *
      * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
      * @return void
      */
      public function execute(
         \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
      ) {

            $customerDataObject = $observer->getCustomerDataObject();
            $origCustomerDataObject = $observer->getOrigCustomerDataObject();

            if (is_null($origCustomerDataObject)) {
               return;
            }

            //If is first update confirm and send email
            try {
                  $customer = 
                     $this->customerRegistry
                        ->retrieve($customerDataObject->getId());

            } catch (Exception $e) {
               return $this;
         }

         if (!$customer->getSentEmail()) {
            //Confirm and send email
            $customer->setConfirmation(null);
            $customer->setSentEmail(1);
            $customer->save();

            //Send email
            $this->emailNotification->newAccount(
               $customerDataObject,
               $type = EmailNotification::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED,
               $backUrl = '',
               $customerDataObject->getStoreId()
            );
         }

         return $this;

      }
   }
```

**magentostackexchange\Sample\Setup\InstallData.php**

```
   <?php

   namespace Magentostackexchange\Sample\Setup;

   use Exception;
   use \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
   use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
   use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
   use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;

   /**
    * @codeCoverageIgnore
    */
   class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
   {
      /**
      * @var CustomerSetupFactory 
      */
      private $customerSetupFactory;

      /**
      * @var AttributeSetFactory 
      */
      private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory 
     */
      private $eavSetupFactory;

      /**
      * InstallData constructor.
      * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
      * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
      * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
      * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
      */
      public function __construct(
         CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
         \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
         \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
         AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
      ) {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
            $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        }

     /**
      * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
      * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
      */
      public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, 
         ModuleContextInterface $context) {

         echo "\n\n********** RUNNING INSTALL DATA (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n";

         $installer = $setup;   

         $installer->startSetup();

         echo "\n********** SETUP STARTED (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n";

         try {

                /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
                $customerSetup = 
                   $this->customerSetupFactory
                      ->create(['setup' => $setup]);

                $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory
                   ->create(['setup' => $setup]);

                $customerEntity = $customerSetup
                   ->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');

                $attributeSetId = $customerEntity
                   ->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

                $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();

                $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet
                   ->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

                // job_title for Customer

                echo "\n********** CREATING JOB_TITLE ATTR FOR CUSTOMER (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********";

                $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'job_title',
                [
                   'type'         => 'varchar',
                   'label'        => 'Job Title',
                   'input'        => 'text',
                   'required'     => true,
                   'visible'      => true,
                   'user_defined' => false,
                   'position'     => 999,
                   'system'       => 0,
                ]
             );

                $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
                   CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                   CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
                   null,
                   'job_title');

                $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                   ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'job_title')
                      ->addData([
                         'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                         'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,

                         'used_in_forms' => 
                            ['adminhtml_customer',
                             'customer_account_create']

                ])->save();

                echo "\n********** JOB_TITLE ATTR FOR CUSTOMER CREATED SUCCESFULLY (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n";

                // Sent Email for Customer

                echo "\n********** CREATING SENT_EMAIL ATTR FOR CUSTOMER (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********";

                $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'sent_email',
                [
                   'type' => 'int',
                   'label' => 'Sent Email',
                   'input' => 'boolean',
                   'source' => '',
                   'required' => true,
                   'visible' => false,
                   'position' => 333,
                   'system' => false,
                   'backend' => '',
                   'default' => 0
                ]
                );

                $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
                   CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                   CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
                   null,
                  'sent_email');

                $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                   ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY,'sent_email')
                      ->addData([
                         'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                         'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                         'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
                      ])->save();

                echo "\n********** SENT_EMAIL ATTR FOR CUSTOMER CREATED SUCCESFULLY (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n";

            } catch (Exception $ex) {

                echo "\n********** ERROR: LOGGING EXCEPTION (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n";

                error_log('MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE MODULE EXCEPTION: ' 
                   . $ex->getMessage());
            }
            finally{

               echo "\n********** EXITING INSTALL DATA (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n";

               $installer->endSetup();

               echo "\n********** INSTALL DATA FINISHED (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n\n";
         }  
      }
   }
```

**magentostackexchange\Sample\Setup\InstallSchema.php**

```
   <?php

   namespace Magentostackexchange\Sample\Setup;

   use Exception;
   use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;


   /**
    * Class InstallSchema
    */
   class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
   {
      /**
      * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
      * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
      */
      public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
            ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {
         echo "\n\n********** RUNNING INSTALL SCHEMA  (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n";

         $setup->startSetup();

         try {

            echo "\n********** SETUP STARTED (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n";

            // Used in UpgradeSchema.php
            // if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) { 

            // sent_email

            echo "\n********** ADDING COLUMN SENT_EMAIL TO CUSTOMER  (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********";

            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
               $setup->getTable('customer_entity'),
                  'sent_email',
                  [
                     'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                     'nullable' => true,
                     'comment' => 'Sent email'
                  ]
            );

            echo "\n********** COLUMN SENT_EMAIL ADDED SUCCESFULLY TO CUSTOMER (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n";

         } catch (Exception $ex) {

            echo "\n********** ERROR: LOGGING EXCEPTION (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n\n";

            error_log('MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE MODULE EXCEPTION: ' 
               . $ex->getMessage());

         }

         // }

         echo "\n********** INSTALL SCHEMA FINISHED (MAGENTOSTACKEXCHANGE_SAMPLE) **********\n\n";
     }
   }
```

**magentostackexchange\Sample\ registration.php**

```
   <?php

   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
      \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
      'Magentostackexchange_Sample',
      __DIR__
   );
```

**Tip**: use **Mage2Gen** to develop the basics of your Magento 2 Modules

https://mage2gen.com/

It is possible to create **Customer** and other entity attributes through an easy interface.

You can generate modules for Magento 2.2 and 2.3:

In Modules generated for version 2.3, custom attribute definitions include partial assignment to the entity attribute set/group